# AJAX Load more post button in custom wp_loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Recently i've made a custom loop for a custom wp theme and I need to implement a button with a "load more" Ajax function.

I need to use button instead of auto-loading because people should also scroll down in the footer.

There is no limit to the load more button. This function would also be implemented in other pages that are using the same loop to display other post types or in search template.

I found some older discussion with some guides but once i've tried them, they won't work.

I don't know how to go, do i need to use pagination? Do I need to rebuild all my loop?

```
<?php $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page'=>5, 'paged' => $paged, 'post_status' => 'publish')); ?>
            <?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="post col-xs-12 col-md-6">

                        <div class="post-container">

                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">

                            <div class="testata-post cover" style="background-image:url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>)">

                                <div class="post-title <?php echo get_the_category( $id )[0]->slug; ?>">

                                    <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
                                    <span><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_date', get_the_date(), get_option( 'd M Y' ), '<span>', '</span>' ); ?></span>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="categoria-post <?php echo get_the_category( $id )[0]->slug; ?>"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Hope that someone can help me, thank for the patience!

Comment: try WordPress Infinite Scroll Plugin

Comment: Sorry, but i really want to learn how to do it because i tend to not use plugins...

Comment: hope this link is helpful for you please check https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/277107/load-more-ajax-on-wp-query

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to check this thread!